# Just how intrusive IS Cortana?

Tags: windows, privacy, windows-10

According to Microsoft's [privacy statement](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/privacystatement/default.aspx?Componentid=pspMainCortanaModule&View=Description):

> To enable Cortana to provide personalized experiences and relevant suggestions, Microsoft collects and uses various types of data, such as your device location, data from your calendar, the apps you use, data from your emails and text messages, who you call, your contacts and how often you interact with them on your device. Cortana also learns about you by collecting data about how you use your device and other Microsoft services, such as your music, alarm settings, whether the lock screen is on, **what you view and purchase, your browse and Bing search history, and more.**

A lot of the things listed are pretty intrusive, but I want to focus on the bold last part. The privacy statement explicitly says Cortana tracks your browsing but is pretty vague on the details.

Does Cortana track your browsing live, or just scan the history? Does it track my browsing only if I use IE/Edge? Or does it track me when using Firefox/Chrome too? What if I use private/incognito browsing modes? Does it still track me?

Even if I used the Tor browser, there's no technical reason Cortana couldn't still track me. Does it?

Comment: This will be very difficult for us to answer. This is more of a Microsoft question since Cortana is still so new.

Comment: At least the Tor part is interesting and i think we should discuss it jere ( i.e a local software is able to track you while on Tor) and i don't think its opinion-based

Comment: @schroeder How is this opinion-based? I asked specific questions that have objective yes/no answers. Just because it's "difficult"?

Comment: Well, unless you can convince Microsoft to release Cortana's entire source code base (and somehow verify it's real), it will be based on speculation and opinions.

Comment: @soong has it right. You asked yes /no  questions, but we can only guess at this point.

Comment: @soong The source code argument is moot, otherwise every question regarding closed source software would have to be closed. Yes, often "is it secure" can only be answered with "no" for closed source software, not with "yes" (generally hard to answer yes), but I think answers which collect facts and observations would be useful, just like a simple "there is an entry in the system settings for this", or "every time i type into tor browser's search bar, I see in wireshark a request to cortana.microsoft.com"

Comment: @user10008 That's a very good point. I think we'll find more out as more details about Cortana are released (because people are bound to have privacy concerns that Microsoft will want to address), though I doubt it will be as easy as wireshark spying - could you imagine the crapstorm that MS would get into if it were transmitting private info in the clear, unencrypted?  With a company this large, we'll hopefully be able to trust that the user agreement and public disclosures are accurate, but I still think it's mostly spyware we need to worry about.

Comment: They can be TLS packets too, the domain isn't encrypted by TLS. And the observation can be time based. Assumed if they used something like GCM, which keeps an XMPP connection open, you'd see TLS packets every time a message was sent, and if wireshark was online the TLS connection was established, you can get the domain.

Comment: @soong It's not a question of being able to trust the user agreement, since the user agreement explicitly says Cortana tracks your browsing. The question is whether it tracks your browsing even when using non-MS browsers and modes of browsing typically considered private.